# Hangfire MSMQ processed in server 1 but stuck in server 2

Tags: msmq, hangfire, hangfire-sql

I'm using Hangfire with MSMQ.
Here is the setup

- 2 Front-end Servers (for IIS), I will call them **web1** and **web2**
- A 3rd server for Hangfire Windows Service (I'll call it app1)
- A load balancer between them.

**Problem**

When I tried to access Hangfire dashboard using the hostname (let's say **koko.com/hangfire**) the message will be enqueued in one of the web servers MSMQs. You can see it in **Outgoing MSMQ messages** in web1 or web2.

So I did more investigation to know why the message is not moving out from Outgoing Messages.

I simply accessed the dashboard from http://localhost/hangfire in **web1** and it works. then I enqueued the jobs from there and it did not work. When I repeat the same process in **web2** it works!

Why enqueuing messages from web2 is working but not in web1?! The messages are stuck in web1 **Outgoing Queues**

Comment: A message stuck in outgoing means that the queue manager on the sending machine cannot connect to the queue manager on the receiving machine. This could be for a number of reasons, eg trust between sender and receiver, firewall on receiving machine, etc. Is the receiving machine the hangfire server?

Comment: @tomredfern yes it is.

Comment: Is there any difference in set up between web1 and the hangfire server and the set up between web2 and the hangfire server?

Comment: There is no difference ... but you know maybe it’s bcz of cloning web2 from web1 ... I will try to delete the queues and build it again.

Comment: In the end, we dropped the whole MSMQ configuration in Hangfire and depend on SQL polling. MSMQ makes things complicated! High availability setup is a nightmare. Check the Configuration that we are using https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/configuration/using-sql-server.html#configuring-the-polling-interval